# Can not produce with dockerized producer into Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, avro, confluent-schema-registry, producer

Did anyone encounter this error ?

```
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]; error code: 50005\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:226)
```

I have this stack trace when I try to produce messages into kafka.

FYI, the kafka stack (kaka, schema-registry and zookeeper) and the producer are dockerized with a docker-compose file.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Your question sounds like 'problem with dockerized producer into Kafka'. Do you able to run the same producer outside Docker?

Comment: Can you show your producer code and Compose file?

Comment: Hi ! Yes, it works perfectly when the producer outside docker.. I think, the schema registry endpoint returned HTML rather than JSON, that's why I have this error but I don't know how I can fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a proxy, I added my IP address to http.nonProxyHosts and it works.
The problem was the schema-registry returning HTML rather than JSON, that's why I had this annoying error.